# move records from details table to history table using stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have a stored procedure which copies records from detail table to history table. It will run once in a day. Volume of records in detail table is few hundred thousand. It is taking more then 2 hrs to copy the detail to history table.

How to improve the performance?

My procedure:

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp_Job_Archive_Record_Count]            
    @p_ToDate  DATETIME,          
    @p_Detail_Ins  INT OUTPUT,          
    @p_Detail_Del INT OUTPUT,          
    @p_Header_Ins INT OUTPUT,          
    @p_Header_Del INT OUTPUT          
as          
BEGIN TRAN    
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED          
    INSERT into tbl_Detail_History    
    SELECT * FROM tbl_Detail WITH(NOLOCK)    
    WHERE i_HeaderKey IN           
    (SELECT i_HeaderKey FROM tbl_Header WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE d_dateTime <= cast(@p_ToDate AS DATETIME)          
    )          

    SET @p_Detail_Ins = @@ROWCOUNT        
    INSERT INTO tbl_Archive_Count values('Detail',@p_Detail_Ins,getdate  (),@p_ToDate)          

    DELETE FROM tbl_detail           
    WHERE i_DetailKey IN          
        (SELECT i_DetailKey FROM tbl_Detail_History WITH(NOLOCK))          

    SET @p_Detail_Del = @@ROWCOUNT                   


    INSERT INTO tbl_Header_History    
    SELECT * FROM tbl_Header WITH(NOLOCK)    
        WHERE d_dateTime <= cast(@p_ToDate as DATETIME)          

    SET @p_Header_Ins = @@ROWCOUNT        
    INSERT INTO tbl_Archive_Count values('Header',@p_Header_Ins,getdate(),@p_ToDate)          

    DELETE FROM tbl_Header    
    WHERE i_Headerkey IN           
    (SELECT i_HeaderKey FROM tbl_Header_History WITH(NOLOCK))          

    SET @p_Header_Del = @@ROWCOUNT     

    IF (@@ERROR <> 0)    
        BEGIN    
            ROLLBACK TRAN       
        END    
COMMIT TRAN
```

Comment: Is there an index on table `tbl_Header` with columns `i_HeaderKey` and `d_dateTime`? What are the clustered indices on `tbl_Detail_History` and `tbl_Header_History`? More specifically, what kind of columns are in those indices? What kind of file growth settings do you have for the database files? What kind of disc(s) are the files on?

Comment: As the history table gets larger, it has more and more ID-values used in the sub-query to check for deletable records in the primary tables. If the datetime fields referred to with the variable are reliable enough, you could just use that to filter what to delete in the primary tables. Either way, try to find a way to reduce the number of rows (simplify the logic) SQL Server has to go through to determine which rows should be deleted.

Comment: It is likely, that [`OUTPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause would be useful here. Use a single statement that deletes rows from `tbl_Detail` and adds these deleted rows into `tbl_Detail_History`.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on indexes and the rows ratio between tbl_detail and tbl_detail_history changing

```
DELETE FROM tbl_detail           
WHERE i_DetailKey IN          
    (SELECT i_DetailKey FROM tbl_Detail_History WITH(NOLOCK))
```

to

```
DELETE FROM tbl_detail  D         
WHERE exists (select 1 from FROM tbl_Detail_History WITH(NOLOCK) where i_DetailKey = d.i_DetailKey)
```

a similiar change can be made with the tbl_header delete. Should you get the performance increase you are looking for I would also suggest removing the no lock hint, particularily on the delete statements as you could cause yourself to have integrity issues there. Have a look at read_committed_snapshot which *could* be of benefit

HTH